# migration to symfony 3 creating forms with variable class Type names

Tags: php, symfony, migration

So i'm migrating my application from symfony 2.8 to symfony 3 so i started but fixing the deprecated like in the migration guide

```
$form = $this->createForm(new MyType())
```

Changes to this

```
$form = $this->createForm(MyType::class);
```

But in my code i have the name of the Typeclass as a variable

```
$frmType = "\\Form\\".$risq->getName().'ProduitType';
$form = $this->createForm(new $frmType(), $ent);
```

And i have no idea how to change this to fix the deprecated method :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`get_class`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) should give you what you need, including the namespace.

```
$frmTypeClass = get_class($risq);
$form = $this->createForm($frmTypeClass, $ent);
```

Comment: Thanks it's working :) but we should give get_class an object and not a string so when i used `$frmTypeClass = get_class(new $frmType()); `it worked just fine. Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad it's working and thanks for noticing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do $frmType or $frmType::class?

Comment: I already tried but it doesn't work `Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' `